# What electronic component is this? It says "K103M" on top

Tags: identification, components

What electronic component is this?

My Multi-function Tester says it is a capacitor with a value of ~8958 pF (= 8.9 nF)

It says "K103M" on top of it. Could this mean that it should be 10*10^3 = 10000 pF?

[image: component tester showing 8958 pF]

[image: closer photo of unknown component]

[image: unknown components next to a ruler]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What electric component is this?

It is a capacitor.

> My Multi-function Tester says it is a capacitor with a value of ~8958
> pF (=8.9 nF)
>
> It says "K103M" on top of it. Could this mean that it should be
> 10*10^3 = 10000 pF?

It is a 10nF capacitor, the K and M I believe are the voltage and tolerance, I believe that the letter at the beginning is the voltage and letter at the end is tolerance although I could be wrong

Depending on tolerance, 8.9nF could be within the tolerance of a 10nF capacitor. If I am correct with the tolerance being the letter M, that is ±20% if I recall correctly, which would mean this capacitor is indeed within tolerance.

You can look for capacitor printed codes on Google to double check values and look more into the voltage and capacitance tolerances.

Comment: To expand on this, that is a capacitor designed for installation by DIP IC insertion equipment. In the 80's, large boards containing only (or predominantly) digital DIP ICs were common, and there was machinery *specifically* for automatic IC placement. These capacitors are designed to work in those machines.